# How to use MATLAB functions in turbo C++?

Tags: matlab, turbo-c++

I'm want to use a Matlab function that I've written in Turbo C++.

I know that I'll have to use .dll, .lib, and .h files that I've extracted from Matlab function.

> **Question:** How can I use the extracted .dll, .lib, and, .h files to call this function in Turbo C++?

Here is my function:

```
function [ Integ ] = integral( x , a,b )
Integ = int(x,a,b);
end
```

Comment: Thought people stopped using Turbo C++ long time ago.

Comment: yes i know, but i must do it

Comment: Hmm. Isn't Turbo C++ going to require a 16 bit dll / ancient version of matlab?

Comment: You have to implement the function and then use. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14005/definite-integral-calculation-in-c This link might help you.

Comment: @drescherjm I also doubt, it will properly integrate with MatLab.